# Why is KML not loading in Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I have a KML file that I am trying to load into Google maps. It zooms somewhere in the water with no route trace. This is the code I am trying:

```
    var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(kml);
    kmlLayer.setMap(this.googlemap);
```

"this.googlemap" has a Google map object. It is very simple example, but maybe I am missing something or my KML is not in the right format. My KML file can be download here: http://temp-share.com/show/gFHKdyG0Y. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Map needs to be able to access this KML file direclty, in other words, your KML file must be  publicly available, and must end with .kml or .kmz extensions (I believe).

To make sure the KML file itself is correct, you can always go to maps.google.com and put the URL in the search bar, it should be automatically recognized and rendered.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It does work when pasting into Google maps. Seems like I might be using the API wrong.

Comment: What is the value of variable kml you passed into KmlLayer constructor?

Answer (score 0):

As Bill says, the KML file needs to be publicly downloadable, however The URL you linked to in the question abov does not link directly to the file itself, it links to an HTML page that you can visit to download the file. You may have to try a different service, as it doesn't appear that you can download directly from that location without going through the intermediate page.

You will know you are using the right link when you paste the link into the browser, and it immediately prompts you to download the file.

If you still have problems, make sure to post more of your code.